# electron-builder generate latest.json instead of latest.yml

Tags: json, yaml, electron-builder

electron-builder generates "latest.yml" blockmap and exe for windows. But in production environment yml is not accepted. Need to change "latest.yml" to "latest.json". What are the configuration require to change "latest.yml" to "latest.json"?

---

electron-builder@^22.9.1

Answer (score 0):

We tried it , there are no configuration options to change to json.We converted from yml to json at jenkins build . Electron-builder is using js-yaml node module to parse the yml response, which will accept both json and yml. If you send json instead of yml present version of electron-updater will accept and works fine.

Comment: Please share the process to convert to yml to json at the time of building